# Best statistic for measuring prediction accuracy: Std Error and R2 VS MAE and RMSE?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, predictive-models

I know there are probably many opinions for what the best way to measure how accurate predictions are using statistics but I have seen some people argue that low Standard Error and high R2 work best together and other people have said that low MSE and RMSE work well together. I have also heard some other statistics like Standard Deviation thrown in. Is there a consensus on these statistics for best to use for future predictions and/or is it up to my personal preference?

Comment: It rather depends on (a) what form the predictions take (e.g. sales next month and predicted probability of rain are rather different) and (b) what the costs of being wrong in different ways are

Comment: @Henry I'm doing time series predictions for future home sales data

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of literature on point forecast error measures for time series forecasting. Different error measures will be minimized by different forecasts! Thus, you should first decide which functional of the unknown future distribution you want to elicit, then use an appropriate error measure that does this. More info in [Kolassa (2020, *IJF*)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017), apologies for the self-promotion.