# Comparing predicted results vs. actual results

Tags: regression, predictive-models, panel-data

I have a dataframe that spans across 6 years (2015-2020), with ~500 companies and several fundamental stats (e.g. sales, # employees, ROA). I used a span of 5 years (2015-2019) to predict the ROA for each company in 2020, in order to compare the predicted ROA (2020) and the actual ROA (2020).

However, now I am unsure of how to best show this difference? Can that be done through a regression? What would I need to be careful of?

Would be grateful for any leads!

Comment: Are you looking for prediction accuracy measures? [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/549622/1352) and [this](https://otexts.com/fpp3/accuracy.html) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do a scatter plot of predicted vs. actual ROA. If the scatter plot makes a perfect diagonal line, then there is a very good agreement.

Comment: If the scatter makes a perfect diagonal line, then there is perfect agreement!  I agree that this plot is often useful and strangely neglected in some fields. Some call it a calibration plot. Further note that calculating residual $=$ observed $-$ predicted and plotting residual versus predicted is often helpful. A perfect fit would follow the horizontal line residual = 0. The calibration plot is sometimes a propaganda plot while the residual versus predicted or fitted plot allows more thought about lack of fit.

Answer (score 0):

You are backtesting your model, conditioning the history data (up to 2019) to predict the 2020.You can just plot (line type) both the predicted and the actual ROA to see how far of how close your predictions are from the actual one.